# How to show a plot made with Ordisurf and Orditorp in rmarkdown without showing output codes

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I'm trying to figure out this issue. I don't want the # with output result but only the plot

````
```{r fig6, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.cap="\\label{fig6}NMDS Querceto, Grafici a Ragno con dati Ambientali", fig.height=5, fig.show='asis', fig.width=5, out.width="50%"}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
ordisurf(Q_NMDS,Env$`Temperatura (C°)`,main="Temperatura",col="forestgreen")
orditorp(Q_NMDS,display="species",col="grey30",air=0.1,
   cex=1)
ordisurf(Q_NMDS,Env$`Umidità (%)`,main="Umidità",col="forestgreen")
orditorp(Q_NMDS,display="species",col="grey30",air=0.1,
   cex=1)
```
````

In the rendered output, I would like to remove these output codes and want just the plot,

[image: I would like to remove these output codes but just the plot]

So I tried to create an object putting plus between codes:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) +
ordisurf(Q_NMDS,Env$`Temperatura (C°)`,main="Temperatura",col="forestgreen") +
orditorp(Q_NMDS,display="species",col="grey30",air=0.1,
   cex=1) +
ordisurf(Q_NMDS,Env$`Umidità (%)`,main="Umidità",col="forestgreen") +
orditorp(Q_NMDS,display="species",col="grey30",air=0.1,
   cex=1)
```

if I put + to create an object to plot I have an error:

```
Error in par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) + ordisurf(Q_NMDS, Env$`Temperature (C°)`, :
   non-numeric argument passed to a binary operator
```

Comment: Not sure why you think adding a `+` in your code will prevent the messages from being printed. Instead I would try with adding `message=FALSE` to the chunk options.

Comment: Oh ya, sorry..
I meant something like this to create new object and plot just that:

new_obj <- par(mfrow=c(1,2)) +
ordisurf(Q_NMDS,Env$`Temperatura (C°)`,main="Temperatura",col="forestgreen") + ecc....

then in another chunk:
New_obj

Comment: Don't think that this works. While there is `+` operator in `ggplot2` as far as I can tell your plots are base R plots. So you can't "add" them together using `+` and hence get an error `non-numeric argument passed to a binary operator`.

Comment: That you for the Answer Stefan! I solved it putting fig.keep='all' and results= 'hide' . Now its working!